# Empty Array Trying to Render Data in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am writing a react native app. I am able to understand how to retrieve data from api data by using axios or fetch. But I am having trouble. I am trying to use my token I passed from the previous class and use that to fetch a new api and data. I am able to connect to the server and I connected fine in POSTMAN. But when I look in my log from terminal in Visual Studio. I get am empty array. I get array = []. But I know that is is supposed to show data.

```
async componentDidMount(){
try {
  const savedProfile = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData');
  const profile = JSON.parse(savedProfile);
  const token = profile.token;
  console.log(token);
  const email = profile.user_email;
  const name = profile.user_nicename;
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers:{
      Accept: 'application/json',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
           Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response));
} catch (err) {
  console.warn(err);
}
};
```

I believe the issue might be in render as with the other posts on this site that I read. I looked at the documentation on the react website too but I may need a little more help. What I was trying to do first was just to print the data in the console. I filled my page with dummy data. But if possible I was hoping to fill my table with a specific part of the json data. Basically fetching address and this is an example.

`"address": "4060 18th Ave NE, Naples, Florida, USA",`

The rest of my render looks like this. But I am hoping to at least show the data in the console so I can go from there.

```
render() {
return (
  <View>
    <Header
      centerComponent={{ text: 'Schedule', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
      containerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#000000',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
      }}
    />
    <FlatList
      data={[
        {key: 'Devin'},
        {key: 'Dan'},
        {key: 'Dominic'},
        {key: 'Jackson'},
        {key: 'James'},
        {key: 'Joel'},
        {key: 'John'},
        {key: 'Jillian'},
        {key: 'Jimmy'},
        {key: 'Julie'},
      ]}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
    />
  </View>
);
}
```

Comment: where does the **url** you have used in fetch come from ?

Comment: @Saadi const url = 'http://ec2-18-223-87-78.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/wp-json/ha-api/v1/list-properties/user/ this requires a token to work by a get request.

Comment: Does it go to the **catch()**?

Comment: @Saadi No. I get a successful connection. Response 201. Which is ok. But I do not get any catch errors or problems. I get my token in console and the empty array and that is all.

Comment: If you execute the link in a browser, it gives you empty array, which means it was successful even if there was no token. Make sure you return error on the server if no token is passed for the fetch to properly work. 
Secondly log  the values of token and make sure that its not empty or expired.

Comment: @Saadi I will take a look at my api created then. I checked the console. I return my token everytime. So I know for a fact that works. I developed an ios swift native app and I know for a fact I can get the data from the same url with token and display the data. Same when viewing in Postman.

Comment: shouldn't the Header part be like this ?

headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
        }

Comment: That was it thank you. Just had to move that!

Comment: could please mark the answer as correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the header parameters in the correct format as below:

```
headers: { 
   'Accept': 'application/json', 
   'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
   'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token, 
 }
```